# Spritekit- SKTextureatlas - Use preloaded textures across multiple scenes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been researching for the past two days for a clear answer to my question and i simply couldn't find one online.

I am developing a game for IOS using sprite kit and i am in the optimisation phase but i ran into a problem. i want to preload all my resources at application launch and then use them across all the scenes and classes in my app.

I understand that is done using the preload function of the texture atlas. i created a .atlas folder named powerUpTex.atlas and this is the function i have written:

First i added a property to the TitleScene as an array

@interface TitleScene : SKScene

@property (strong) NSArray *textureData;

@end

//I placed the textures in the array in the function that loads the game scene
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"powerUpTex"];

```
    SKTexture *powerUp1 = [atlas textureNamed: powerUp1ImageName];
    SKTexture *powerUp2  = [atlas textureNamed: powerUp2ImageName];
    SKTexture *powerUp3 = [atlas textureNamed: powerUp3ImageName];

    textureData = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    textureData= @[powerUp1,powerUp2,powerUp3];

    [SKTexture preloadTextures:textureData withCompletionHandler:^{
         NSLog(@"textures loaded");
         //Load the GameScene
    }
```

My application contains the following classes:
1.App Delegate

2.ViewController

3.TitleScene

4.GameScene

5.HelperClass1 (is called by the game scene and returns an SKSprite node using the preloaded textures)

6.HelperClass2 (is called by the game scene and returns an SKSprite node using the preloaded textures)

7.GameOverScene

ok so my questions are:

First, Where should i place this function (as in in what class). in the app delegate? view controller? title scene?

Second and more importantly, where are the textures preloaded into and HOW can i access them within the app from any scene or class! if for example i want to use the powerUp1 texture in the HelperClass2 to initialise a skspritenode, how can i do that in code?

I have been experimenting for over a day with no success. i would appreciate a reply that includes a code snippet i can use.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm going through exactly what you were. There's no answer in the documentation or anywhere that I can find that answers this clearly. Best I've come across is an offhand comment saying that loading textures in say the App Delegate or the VC, and holding a reference to them there, will allow you to create SKTextures in your scenes (say the GameScene) that won't need time to move the image to memory as it's already there for the App Delegate (or VC if that's where you did it). A comment not an answer because I can't substantiate it. Would love it if someone could.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your texture inside your ViewController as a singleton or as a NSMutableDictionary which is a public property of ViewController for e.g.

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController

@property NSMutableDictionary *level1Textures;
@property NSMutableDictionary *level2Textures;
@property NSMutableDictionary *level3Textures;

@end
```

now you can access those NSMutableDictionary in every SKScene by using =

```
gameViewController=(UIViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController
```

where gameViewController is a instance of UIViewController now you can access  level1Textures and level2Textures because they are public properties of  UIViewController

Comment: I am sorry but this method did not work. i tried the code u provided and when i tried to access the properties by typing gameViewController. the properties i defined in the view controller dont show as options.

in addition, why aren't we using atlases and the preload method? aren't those the most efficient for sprite kit?